old parody about sperm
I'm trying to recall a movie/skit, likely back in the 90s. It was a parody about sperm living in a man. They were actually real men, dressed in diapers. In one part of the movie, it showed the sperm (men) drinking and partying, while one was working out, with the intent to be the first to reach the egg, only to find out it was a false alarm.  I know it sounds crazy, but this movie was funny as heck. Can't seem to remember the name. Help.

Are you sure it was the 90's?  This sounds likee a scene in  "Everything You Always Wanted To Know About Sex, But Were Afraid To Ask" but that movie was made in 1972, not the 90's.

Here's the relevant part of the movie @steelerfan mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dh4LikiGBrQ (the sperms appear close to the middle of that clip) — is that what you remember?

The movie you are looking for sounds like Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Sex (But Were Afraid to Ask) A film directed by and starring Woody Allen from 1972.
The movie is a sequence of short skits depicting different sexual situations.
The scene you are describing is the last skit in the film:

What Happens During Ejaculation? The NASA-like mission control center
  in a man's brain (headed by Tony Randall and featuring Burt Reynolds
  as the switchboard operator) is seen, as he gets involved in a sexual
  clinch with an NYU graduate (Erin Fleming) (knowledge that she is a
  graduate of NYU assures coital success). As he achieves orgasm, the
  soldier-like, white-uniformed sperm (one of them played by
  bespectacled Allen, coached by another sperm played by Robert Walden)
  are dispatched paratrooper-style into the great unknown.




